# library X11_Xmu_LIB is not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to install the library X11_Xmu_LIB, which is needed to build a project (with cmake)
I have tried several way to install the library, (let me start by saying I am using ubuntu with wsl in windows)

I tried: `sudo apt-get install libxt-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev`

The library was correctly installed, however when I run cmake I still receive the same error: -lX11_Xmu_LIB-NOTFOUND

Anyone knows what I can do?